# Translate by moving mouse curser over word (similar to TranslateIt!)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, translation

[TranslateIt!](http://www.gettranslateit.com/) (for Windows and Mac) can translate words in any place of the desktop (or almost any) under the mouse cursor.

The main requirement is that the application can recognize words under the cursor, other details (like the languages it translates to/from) are not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/) and [StarDict](http://stardict-4.sourceforge.net/) are pretty fits to these requirements. But StarDict seems works not very good: it not always can recognize a word under cursor. GoldenDict can't recognize word under a cursor too, with GoldenDict you should copy a word into clipboad in order to recognize it (Ctr+C+C). But GoldenDict have more convinient and understandable GUI, which is much easier to use.